# cabal with freeze file fails to build

Tags: cabal

I have used `cabal freeze` on a computer and try to build the same program on another computer. I understand that `cabal build` should compile now the exact same configuration, but I encounter a conflict. The start of the error is:

```
daino.cabal is up-to-date
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: daino-0.1.5.3.1 (user goal)
[__1] trying: unix-2.7.2.2/installed-2.7.2.2 (dependency of daino)
[__2] next goal: bytestring (dependency of unix)
[__2] rejecting: bytestring-0.11.3.1/installed-0.11.3.1 (constraint from
project config /home/frank/Workspace11/daino/cabal.project.freeze requires
==0.11.4.0)
[__2] rejecting: bytestring-0.11.4.0 (conflict: unix =>
bytestring==0.11.3.1/installed-0.11.3.1)
[__2] rejecting: bytestring-0.11.3.1, bytestring-0.11.3.0,
bytestring-0.11.2.0, bytestring-0.11.1.0, bytestring-0.11.0.0,
bytestring-0.10.12.1, bytestring-0.10.12.0, bytestring-0.10.10.1,
bytestring-0.10.10.0, bytestring-0.10.9.0, byte
```

I cannot understand the error. It should install `unix-2.7.2.2` which requires `bytestring <0.12` and the freeze asks for `any.bytestring ==0.11.4.0,`.

why does `cabal build` not try 0.11.4.0 but rejects 0.11.3.1? It should not matter, that 0.11.3.1 is installed?

What is my misconception of `freeze`? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have received help on github on the cabal issues page ([here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/9021)). The error are caused by the differences between the ghc compiler used: 9.2.5 and 9.2.7; they are both based on the same version of base (4.16.4) but there are some more differences in the version of `bytestring` which is built into the compiler.

Moving both compiler to the exact same verion resolves the issue!